# How to use @FindAll and @FindBy in Selenium by XPath for Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

[Website](https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E4%B8%A4%E4%BB%B6%E5%A5%97%E5%A5%97%E8%A3%85%E8%A3%99&enc=utf-8&wq=%E4%B8%A4%E4%BB%B6%E5%A5%97%E5%A5%97%E8%A3%85%E8%A3%99&pvid=c35452079d6240b3a5fab6c585b53856)

I use this method to scarp elements

```
name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="p-name p-name-type-2"]/a/em/font[3]/font')
```

but when I want inner product details then I have to move for scraping to that item page (Single Product page)

then I only access that item data but I want to scrap all the items data.
It gives 1 item of data, but I want all the item's data.

[All The Outer Details of Products (I know How to scrap this) With the arrow. But do not know how to scrap the inner details of all the items that are shown in picture 2 (next link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf4Tk.jpg)

[I want to scrap these details that are indicated by the red color arrow by xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvm3d.jpg)

Comment: may be cause `//div[@class="p-name p-name-type-2"]/a/em/font[3]/font` just has one unique entry in HTMLDOM?

Comment: @cruisepandey I want to scrap all the products data. I do not know what to do. Outer details of the products are being scraped but the inner detail of the product is not being scraped. Just single inner single product detail is being scraped. Now I want all the inner details of all the prodcuts.

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks for your response! but it's giving a slow result as it's opening the one-by-one product and scraping one by one.

Comment: There's nothing much we can do about it, that's the standard procedure with selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape internal data of the products, you will have to click on them one by one and then it will open in a new tab, so you will have to switch to a new tab then you should be able to scrape it.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=两件套套装裙&enc=utf-8&wq=两件套套装裙&pvid=c35452079d6240b3a5fab6c585b53856")

all_products = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@data-img and not(@data-url) and @height='220']")))

print(len(all_products))
i= 1
for product in all_products:
    prd = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//img[@data-img and not(@data-url) and @height='220'])[{i}]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", prd)
    prd.click()
    all_handles = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sku-name"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.p-price"))).text)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[0])
    i = i + 1
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Website response is very slow, so I could not run the entire execution. However, the above code should work fine in your region.

Also, Stackoverflow is not letting me post the output as it contains some special chars.Please see the comment for the output.

Comment: Script output: `希区高端时尚套装女时髦洋气2022年早春秋新款气质名媛套装裙两件套 柠檬黄衬衫(预售8月25日后发货) XS
￥ 459.00
 宏资琦 连衣裙女装新款2022年夏季韩版气质小个子两件套套装裙宽松显瘦时尚百搭小香风连衣裙子女夏天 白色上衣+半身裙 S
￥ 128.00
欧迪惠 连衣裙女22年夏季流行新款两件套套装裙高腰雪纺裙子女中长款气质时尚一字肩上衣刺绣套装女显瘦 蓝白 M
￥ 98.00
衣典零一 两件套套装裙2022春装新款春季女装春秋时尚气质遮肚子显瘦长袖小西装连衣裙半身裙套装长裙子 图片色 M
￥ 259.00
 古伊芙2022年新款连衣裙春夏装女韩版时尚小香风两件套套装裙子潮长袖休闲气质高收腰显瘦早春季女装秋冬 蓝色 M
￥ 159.00
衣典零一两件套套装裙2022春装新款春季女装春秋时尚气质遮肚子显瘦长袖小西装连衣裙百褶裙吊带裙长裙子 灰色 XL
￥ 249.00
 蔓尔依 连衣裙套装女夏季2022新款女装韩版茶歇法式复古初恋甜美温柔风碎花吊带长裙子女两件套套装裙 单件碎花裙 XL
￥ 99.00
随影衣飘 连衣裙夏2022年夏季新款女装韩版显瘦修身小个子女生短袖两件套套装连衣裙女 图片色 L
￥ 188.00`